# Unifying object oriented language

Tags: programming-languages, object-oriented

I'm not sure if this is off-topic but I was thinking about the following: many modern (object-oriented) programming languages are very similar at their core, i.e. they share language features like iterative functions, classes, objects, inheritance, polymorphism etc. Has anyone ever attempted to create a "unifying" (maybe pseudo-code) language that captures all the features shared by those languages such that it would be easy to e.g. compile it to any of them?